# Nginx rule to redirect to a blog subdomain just spins

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have tried some Nginx rewrite for my new site

**Blog**

[www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/](http://www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/)
blog.qwerty.com/educator/

> DesiredURL, Actual URL, Nginx_Rule

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com/blog/category/educator-blog/;
    return 301 $scheme:// blog.example.com/educator/$request_uri;
}
```

**Also tried this :**

```
location /educator {
rewrite ^/educator(.*)$ http://www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/$1 redirect;
  rewrite ^/educator-categoryid-(.*)-productid-(.*).htm$ /educator.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2;
}
```

I've rebuilt with the applied rules but it seems to just spin, some fixed URL. Does the order of the rules matter?

Comment: As the error indicates, that is not valid syntax for the Nginx [rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: If i remove my url from the block its wont showing any error as example =  location /researcher {

  rewrite ^/researcher-categoryid-(.*)-productid-(.*).htm$ /researcher.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2;
}

Comment: I'm not sure where do i put or configure those URL  = new site: www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/
old site : blog.qwerty.com/educator/

Comment: Are you asking about the hostname (e.g. `www.example.com` and `blog.example.com`)? Nginx should handle each of these domains in [separate `server` blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). You place the `rewrite` statements in the `server` block that handles `blog.example.com`.

Comment: Please correct me if I’m wrong , does it work this way !                                                                server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  blog.qwerty.com/educator/    
                 www.qwerty.com/blog/category/educator-blog/

    ...
}

Comment: location /blog {
   rewrite ^/blog/category/educator-blog-categoryid-(.*)-productid-(.*).htm$ /blog/category/educator-blog.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2;
  rewrite ^/blog/category/researcher-blog-categoryid-(.*)-productid-(.*).htm$ /blog/category/researcher-blog.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2;
  rewrite ^/blog/category/librarian-blog-categoryid-(.*)-productid-(.*).htm$ /blog/category/librarian-blog.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2;
}